# PHP encoding to 64 char length

Tags: php, string, encoding, timestamp

To generate some pretty URLs I would take two strings

-UNIX timestamp

-string (length 16 chars)

Is there some way to use both and encode them to a string with a fixed length of 64 chars?

Comment: Are you planning on decoding it later, or do you really mean hash? Does 64 chars have a special meaning or is it just an arbitrary number?

Comment: It should be for a pretty url (example /order/xyz). The xyz should be always a 64 char string I will of course encode it later to retrieve order.

Comment: I'm not sure you can encrypt a string to exactly 64 chars (or why having being exactly 64 chars is that important). Try to use some common encryption and just append or prepend the amount of chars that's missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `str_pad()` function along with base64_encode for the string:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

> This functions returns the input string padded on the left, the right, or both sides to the specified padding length. If the optional argument pad_string is not supplied, the input is padded with spaces, otherwise it is padded with characters from pad_string up to the limit.

Example:

```
$string = urlencode(base64_encode($string));
$padded = str_pad($tstamp."_".$string."_", 64, "0");
```

Your url could then look like:

`/order/timestamp_base64string_00000..../`

Each `_` separator gets you the part of the URL you need, you will have to `urldecode()` then `base64_decode()` the string.

I suggest that you rather use sessions (cookies) to maintain such information from a page to another, or use an intermediary storage system whose IDs could be used in URLs.

Comment: Check my answer above :).